# Does the User Defined Functions (UDF) in SPARK works in a distributed way?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, distributed-computing, databricks

Does the User Defined Functions (UDF) in SPARK works in a distributed way if data is stored in different nodes or it accumulates all data into the master node for processing purpose? If it works in a distributed way then can we convert any function in python whether it's pre-defined or user-defined into spark UDF like mentioned below :

> spark.udf.register("myFunctionName", functionNewName)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark dataframe is distributed across the cluster in partitions. Each partition is processed by the UDF, so the answer is yes. You can also see this in Spark UI.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In that case, can I register any pre-defined function in python as spark UDF and run it in a distributed manner?

Comment: Yes, you can, then it will run in a distributed manner.

Comment: How do the worker nodes know the code of the UDF, since you can't serialize lambdas?

Comment: I don’t know the internal process but udf are processed in each node.